# command line menu options

Tags: bash, scripting

I have been trying to get my menu to work, however it seems that it only accepts one argument/option at a time, how can I get it to accept multiple options?

```
#!/bin/bash

##### Main

function usage
{
    echo "
usage: infinidb [[-f file ] [-i] | [-h]]  name ...
}

        while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
        case $1 in
            -f | --file )           shift
                                    filename=$1
                                    ;;
            -i |  )                 filename2=$2
                                    ;;
            -h | --help )           usage
                                    exit
                                    ;;
            * )                     usage
                                    exit 1
        esac
        shift
    done

            echo $filename 
            echo $filename2
```

when running the script

the following output show show

./script.sh -f apple -i tree

apple tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
#!/bin/bash

    while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
    case $1 in
        -f | --file )           shift
                                filename=$1
                                ;;
        -i )                 filename2=$2
                                ;;
    esac
    shift
done

        echo $filename 
        echo $filename2
```

There was only a problem with `-i | )`

Comment: it works, thank you very much, just wondering if it is possible to add more menu options? I tried adding -b with variable filename3 and I would like it to echo as well, but it didn't work.

Comment: In general there is no limitation. You have to be careful with the `shift`s